# ActiveMQ Artemis - max-delivery-attempts more than 7

Tags: activemq-artemis

I'm using ActiveMQ Artemis 2.17.0, and I am trying to set `max-delivery-attempts` to 10 but it is not working properly for values greater than 7.

Here are my `address-settings` from `broker.xml`:

```xml
      <address-settings>
         <!-- if you define auto-create on certain queues, management has to be auto-create -->
         <address-setting match="activemq.management#">
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
            <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
            <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
            <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
            <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
            <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
            <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
         </address-setting>
         <!--default for catch all-->
         <address-setting match="#">
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
            <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
            <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
            <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
            <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
            <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
            <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
            <max-delivery-attempts>10</max-delivery-attempts>
         </address-setting>
      </address-settings>
```

I am using the test software provided as an example. This software uses OpenWire protocol, and I noticed that ActiveMQ properties are being ignored. I also noticed that I can set the maximum number of delivery attempts directly in the software. It works fine now, but why can't I control it from the server?

Any idea?

Comment: I am using the test software provided as an example. This software uses OpenWire protocol and I noticed that ActiveMQ properties are being ignored. I also noticed that I can set the maximum number of delivery attempts directly in the software, it works fine now, but the question is why I can't control it from the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OpenWire protocol (used by the ActiveMQ "Classic" 5.x client) implements redelivery on the *client* side via a "redelivery policy." You can read more about this in [the documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/redelivery-policy.html). You'll note that the default `maximumRedeliveries` is `6`.

Because of this client-side implementation the broker-side controls can't be properly enforced. In short, the broker has no idea that any redelivery is even happening on the client.

You can either perform your redelivery configuration on the client (i.e via the redelivery policy) or switch to the ActiveMQ Artemis JMS client implementation which will require a new jar and possibly a reconfigured connection URL.